# Form Me.close doesn't work, Close all forms?

Tags: vb.net

I use this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Settings.Str -= 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        Label2.Text = My.Settings.Str
        If My.Settings.Str >= 0 Then
            FrmLogin.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

        If My.Settings.Str <= 0 Then

            MsgBox("Your trial has Expired, Please Buy a key", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Trial Expired")
            FrmRegister.ShowDialog()

        End If
    End Sub
```

But when i run the form and press the button will close all forms
when i use me.hide the code running whitout any problem
can i know if there is any porblem on the code please

Comment: Is this form the start-up form for the application?

Comment: Project > Properties > Application tab, Shutdown mode = "When last form closes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default project settings, your application will be closed when the startup form is closed. If you want to change this behaviour:

1. Right click on your project in the *Solution Explorer*
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select the *Application* tab
4. Under *Shutdown mode*, select "*When last form  closes*" (see image below)

[image: Screenshot]

Another idea would be to leave the default settings and change your startup form...